# Using dictionaries with ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

In my view:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, int>> fs in item.dicFS)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fs.Key.ToString())</td>

                @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> lbl in item.dicFS[fs.ToString()])
                {
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lbl.Value.ToString())</td>
                }

            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

This is the line highlighted when the application crashes

```
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fs.Key.ToString())</td>
```

My model contains a public dictionary that contains a string key and a dictionary value (nested dictionary)

```
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dicFS;
```

The keys and the nested dictionary are initialized and values are assigned by a method within the model.

Am I not allowed to use dictionaries? Do I have to convert my model's data type to a nested array instead of using nested dictionary?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.ToString()` inside `DisplayFor()` method.

Just remove the .ToString() and you should be good

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, int>> fs in item.dicFS)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fs.Key)</td>

                @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> lbl in item.dicFS[fs.ToString()])
                {
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lbl.Value)</td>
                }

            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Well I'll be darned... I was anticipating some complex resolution. I had no idea. thank you!